# Why is my variable value set to false even after it's set to true?

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I am trying to implement google reCAPTCHA. The issue is even when `($Return->success == true && $Return->score >= 0.5)` is equal to true, when i should be getting `$isOK = true`, I get `$isOK = false`.

I tried a lot, but I am still getting this value set to false. Is there something I am doing wrong over here?

```
$captchaVerified = false;
if(isset($_POST['tokenVal'])){
    function getCaptcha($tokenV,$secretKey){
        $Response =  file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".urlencode($secretKey)."&response=".urlencode($tokenV));
        $Return = json_decode($Response);
        /* global $captchaVerified;*/
        if ($Return->success == true && $Return->score >= 0.5) {
            $captchaVerified = true;
        } else {
            $captchaVerified = false;
        }
        return $captchaVerified;
    }
   $isOK = getCaptcha($_POST['tokenVal'],$secretKey);
}
```

Comment: How do you check the value? DO you output it? Where and how?

Comment: I output it using $isOk and can see in debugger that it sets to true when it meet the condition ($Return->success == true && $Return->score >= 0.5). But after being set to true its gain set to false when it exits the function.

Comment: That's impossible. How do you know it "meets the condition"? Also, are you testing `$isOK` after the function, or `$captchaVerified`? There is no reason for the latter to be defined outside the function, and it'll remain `false` there.

Comment: I found the issue. I was mistakenly checking the value $captchaVerified which was being reset to its global value. @Jeto you were right.

Answer (score 0):

The given Response code is performing a ***GET*** request to the api server.

The ***api*** server is expecting a ***POST*** request.

```
$Response =  file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".urlencode($secretKey)."&response=".urlencode($tokenV));
```

To make POST request to the server you can follow these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php) .

The overall reference has been taken from [verify recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api_request)